¿Cómo puedo corregir la conexión WebSocket con el servidor de host de la extensión remota?
Al ejecutar el comando: code <nombre_proyecto> desde WSL y entrar a Visual Studio Code, me ha saltado este error: " Error al conectar con el servidor de host de la extensión remota (Error: WebSocket close with status code 1006) "  El error solamente se produce con mis conexiones remotas procedentes de WSL. Hasta el momento no he encontrado nada por internet que me ayude a solucionar el problema ¿Alguna recomendación? 

1.- Reiniciar el subsistema/distribución:
1.1 Parar con wsl --shutdown (para todas las distros) o wsl -t <distro> (para una distro en concreto).
1.2 Arrancar con wsl (para la distro por defecto) o wsl -d <distro> (para una distro en concreto).
2.- Actualizar el subsistema con wsl --update.
3.- Limpiar el directorio ~/.vscode-server en tu subsistema.

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
